# Looping through values to make changes in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a code that makes some changes in a dataframe.

```
 value <- iris[1:120,]
 
 cngfunc <- function(day,howmany,howmuch){
   shuffled= day[sample(1:nrow(day)), ]
   n = as.integer((howmany/100)*nrow(day)) #select percentage of data to be changed
   extracted <- shuffled[1:n, ]
   extracted$changed <- extracted[,1]*((howmuch/100)+1) #how much the data changes
   extracted}
   
cngfunc(value,10,20)
```

Now I want to loop through the values of `howmany` and `howmuch`.
For example, `howmuch <- c(10,20,30,40,50)` and `howmany <- c(10,20,30,40,50)`
So the first result would be for `cngfunc(value,10,10)`, `cngfunc(value,10,20)`,`cngfunc(value,10,30)`....and `cngfunc(value,20,10)`, `cngfunc(value,20,20)`, and so on such that I'll have 25 different data frame.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `expand.grid` to get all of the combinations, and the a `map2` to create a list of dataframes:

```r
library(tidyverse)

combos <- expand.grid(c(10,20,30,40,50), c(10,20,30,40,50))

result <- map2(combos$Var1, combos$Var2, function(x, y) cngfunc(value, x, y)) %>%
  setNames(tidyr::unite(combos, Var, Var1:Var2, sep = "-")$Var)
```

Not sure where you are getting 120 dataframes from, as 5 * 5 = 25. This should be the general idea though.

Comment: Thank you I'll try it. Sorry, I made a mistake while asking it should be 25.

Comment: If it works, please make sure to leave a check mark so others can see that this answer is a correct one. Let me know how it goes.